# OSError: dlopen(libiodbc.dylib, 6): image not found (Mac Big Sur, Python3.8)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, odbc, teradata, macos-big-sur

I just upgraded my Mac from Mojave to Big Sur, and reinstalled Anaconda and teradata ODBC.  In my Python(3.8) code, I use sqlalchemy-teradata to connect to teradata.  This used to work, but after all the upgrading, my code throws the following error when pulling data from teradata:

```
--> 166         demand=pd.read_sql(sql, con=cnxn)
    167     except:
    168         print("sql string: "+sql)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in read_sql(sql, con, index_col, coerce_float, params, parse_dates, columns, chunksize)
    507         )
    508     else:
--> 509         return pandas_sql.read_query(
    510             sql,
    511             index_col=index_col,

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in read_query(self, sql, index_col, coerce_float, parse_dates, params, chunksize)
   1293         args = _convert_params(sql, params)
   1294 
-> 1295         result = self.execute(*args)
   1296         columns = result.keys()
   1297 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in execute(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1159     def execute(self, *args, **kwargs):
   1160         """Simple passthrough to SQLAlchemy connectable"""
-> 1161         return self.connectable.execution_options(no_parameters=True).execute(
   1162             *args, **kwargs
   1163         )

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py in execute(self, statement, *multiparams, **params)
   2232         """
   2233 
-> 2234         connection = self._contextual_connect(close_with_result=True)
   2235         return connection.execute(statement, *multiparams, **params)
   2236 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py in _contextual_connect(self, close_with_result, **kwargs)
   2300         return self._connection_cls(
   2301             self,
-> 2302             self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, None),
   2303             close_with_result=close_with_result,
   2304             **kwargs

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py in _wrap_pool_connect(self, fn, connection)
   2334         dialect = self.dialect
   2335         try:
-> 2336             return fn()
   2337         except dialect.dbapi.Error as e:
   2338             if connection is None:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py in connect(self)
    364                 return rec._checkout_existing()
    365 
--> 366         return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self, self._fairy)
    367 
    368     def _return_conn(self, record):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py in _checkout(cls, pool, threadconns, fairy)
    776     def _checkout(cls, pool, threadconns=None, fairy=None):
    777         if not fairy:
--> 778             fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
    779 
    780             fairy._pool = pool

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py in checkout(cls, pool)
    493     @classmethod
    494     def checkout(cls, pool):
--> 495         rec = pool._do_get()
    496         try:
    497             dbapi_connection = rec.get_connection()

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py in _do_get(self)
    347         except AttributeError:
    348             pass
--> 349         c = self._create_connection()
    350         self._conn.current = weakref.ref(c)
    351         if len(self._all_conns) >= self.size:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py in _create_connection(self)
    307         """Called by subclasses to create a new ConnectionRecord."""
    308 
--> 309         return _ConnectionRecord(self)
    310 
    311     def _invalidate(self, connection, exception=None, _checkin=True):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py in __init__(self, pool, connect)
    438         self.__pool = pool
    439         if connect:
--> 440             self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
    441         self.finalize_callback = deque()
    442 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py in __connect(self, first_connect_check)
    659         except Exception as e:
    660             with util.safe_reraise():
--> 661                 pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
    662         else:
    663             if first_connect_check:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py in __exit__(self, type_, value, traceback)
     66             self._exc_info = None  # remove potential circular references
     67             if not self.warn_only:
---> 68                 compat.raise_(
     69                     exc_value,
     70                     with_traceback=exc_tb,

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py in raise_(***failed resolving arguments***)
    180 
    181         try:
--> 182             raise exception
    183         finally:
    184             # credit to

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py in __connect(self, first_connect_check)
    654         try:
    655             self.starttime = time.time()
--> 656             connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
    657             pool.logger.debug("Created new connection %r", connection)
    658             self.connection = connection

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py in connect(connection_record)
    112                         if connection is not None:
    113                             return connection
--> 114                 return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
    115 
    116             creator = pop_kwarg("creator", connect)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py in connect(self, *cargs, **cparams)
    491     def connect(self, *cargs, **cparams):
    492         # inherits the docstring from interfaces.Dialect.connect
--> 493         return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
    494 
    495     def create_connect_args(self, url):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/teradata/tdodbc.py in __init__(self, dbType, system, username, password, autoCommit, transactionMode, queryBands, odbcLibPath, dataTypeConverter, driver, **kwargs)
    419 
    420         # Initialize connection handle
--> 421         init(odbcLibPath)
    422 
    423         # Build connect string

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/teradata/tdodbc.py in init(odbcLibPath)
    364     try:
    365         lock.acquire()
--> 366         initOdbcLibrary(odbcLibPath)
    367         initFunctionPrototypes()
    368         initOdbcEnv()

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/teradata/tdodbc.py in initOdbcLibrary(odbcLibPath)
    317                     odbcLibPath = 'libodbc.so'
    318             logger.info("Loading ODBC Library: %s", odbcLibPath)
--> 319             odbc = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(odbcLibPath)
    320 
    321 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py in LoadLibrary(self, name)
    457 
    458     def LoadLibrary(self, name):
--> 459         return self._dlltype(name)
    460 
    461 cdll = LibraryLoader(CDLL)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error, winmode)
    379 
    380         if handle is None:
--> 381             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    382         else:
    383             self._handle = handle

OSError: dlopen(libiodbc.dylib, 6): image not found
```

I can see this libiodbc.dylib right under /usr/lib.  Similarly, my ODBC Manager cannot find libiodbcinst.dylib.  Seems to be the same problem.  I've spent 2 days searching for solutions.  I tried disabling SIP, updating brew, adding /usr/lib to DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, but none of them worked.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Perhaps this is an error related to iODBC driver manager (www.iodbc.org)? Or you might consider changing to from `sqlalchemy-teradata` to `teradatasqlalchemy` package which does not depend on ODBC.

Comment: Thanks for helping!  To make sure I didn't miss anything -- is the "iODBC driver manager" you referred to the same one that Mac OS has on it own?  I didn't install any iODBC driver manager, since I can see the file in /usr/lib.  I did install teradata's ODBC.  If I didn't miss any other installation, I think I'll give teradatasqlalchemy a try.  Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: Well, I went ahead and installed iodbc from iodbc.org anyway, but still didn't work.  So will turn to teradatasqlalchemy now.

Comment: Thank you! teradatasqlalchemy worked!

Answer (score 0):

apple stopped shipping certain libraries with macos big sur, but instead chooses to ship dynamic library cache which as you've found out might not work with certain build systems. below is a github comment that explains this as well.

i'd suggest using your favorite package manager to fill in the missing library and update your build settings to use it instead.

https://github.com/LouisBrunner/valgrind-macos/issues/21#issuecomment-731230554